# scala is 2.10.1 but sbt console is not?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm new to Scala/SBT, so please be gentle, but I'm trying to work my way through the SBT "Getting Started" and I noticed a discrepancy between my brew installed scala and sbt tools.  When I launch the REPL for scala directly, it reports itself as Scala 2.10.1, which is what I would expect.

```
bobk-mbp:work bobk$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_17).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :quit
```

When I launch the REPL through SBT, the REPL asserts it is 2.9.2?!?

```
bobk-mbp:work bobk$ sbt console
[info] Set current project to default-690573 (in build file:/Users/bobk/work/)
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_17).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :quit
```

What's up with that?  I was expecting the build tool to use the scala environment that is hosted on my dev box.  Where is it getting 2.9.2 and how do I get it to use the 2.10.1?

Both scala and sbt were installed via brew, but I don't think that really matters.  The sbt version appears to be 0.12.3

```
bobk-mbp:work bobk$ sbt --version
sbt launcher version 0.12.3
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you start sbt with no parameters:

```
sbt
> ++ 2.10.1
> console
```

should give you Scala 2.10.1 for that session. I don't know how to make it the default for all sbt sessions without rebuilding sbt itself.

Comment: No joy.  Neither [sbt console ++ 2.10.1 ] nor [sbt ++ 2.10.1 console ] work from the command line.  I thought maybe I go into sbt and try the '++ 2.10.1' from there, to no avail.  I found I can force a Scala version through the build.sbt file as scalaVersion := "2.10.1".  I remain surprised that sbt uses a version of Scala other than the one I have deployed on my machine.

Comment: Invoke sbt with no arguments. At the prompt enter ++ 2.10.1. Then type 'console' to enter the console.

Comment: Or you might like:   sbt "++ 2.10.1" console

Answer (score 19):

Sbt downloads the scala doesnt need to have an installed one.

If you want to define something global use the ~/.sbt/global.sbt

In global.sbt you can insert scalaVersion := "2.10.1" and if you want to use your local installed version also define scalaHome := Some(file("/home/iraklis/apps/scala-2.10.1"))

For more detail visit sbt documentation ([link](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0-SNAPSHOT/docs/index.html))

Comment: This works too.  I'm working my way through the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `scalaVersion` in your `build.sbt` or `Build.scala` would help you fix scala version for your current project. [Read here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Howto/scala.html)

```
name := "Sample"

scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

version := "1.1-RELEASE"
```